# Attribute value shows 'no' when it is 'yes' on category listing frontend Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, product-attribute, product-list

I have a very strange issue with my store. I have an **attribute (yes/no value)** and when I echo the value on the **listings page on the frontend** of my **Magento 2 store** all products show the value as 'no'.

Some of them are certainly set to *yes* and I have confirmed this in the admin panel.

**List.phtml**

```
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): $i++ ?>
            <?php $clearClass = $themeHelper->getClearClass($perrow, $i) ?>
            <li class="item product product-item <?php if($viewMode == 'grid'): ?> grid-template-<?php echo $grid_tp ?> <?php echo $colClass ?> <?php echo $clearClass ?><?php endif ?>">
                <?php $swatches = $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>
                <?php $wlDataPost = $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_product); ?>
                <?php $fk = $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                <?php $review = $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>
                <?php $prdPrice = $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>

                <?php echo $this->getLayout()
                                ->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')
                                ->setProduct($_product)
                                ->setThemeHelper($themeHelper)
                                ->setImageHelper($_imagehelper)
                                ->setCatalogHelperOutput($_helper)
                                ->setQuickViewHelper($quickViewHelper)
                                ->setRatio($ratio)
                                ->setSize($size)
                                ->setCustomAttribute($ct_attr)
                                ->setPadding($padding)
                                ->setLazyLoadBaseImage($baseImage)
                                ->setCompare($showCompare)
                                ->setFk($fk)
                                ->setPostParams($postParams)
                                ->setReview($review)
                                ->setPrdPrice($prdPrice)
                                ->setWishList($showWishList)
                                ->setLazyLoad($lazyLoad)
                                ->setHoverChange($change_img)
                                ->setWishListPost($wlDataPost)
                                ->setTemplate($templateFile)
                                ->setSwatches($swatches)
                                ->setPos($pos)
                                ->toHtml(); ?>


               //This is the specific piece of code to get the attribute

              <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('can_buy') ; ?>

            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Can anyone please suggest what may be happening here a fix?

Comment: Did you confirm if they have the correct value saved at store scope level?

Comment: Yes and it is as expected. I also use this attribute in the product/view section and it shows the value correctly... very strange!